# how can i dynamically create ajax links for the returned Json

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following javaScript which will be executed when the page loads:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/package/list?loginAs=admin",

        dataType: "JSONP",
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {

                // Format the text to display.
                var str = val.packageName ;
                // Add a list item for the product.
                $('<li/>', { text: str })
                .appendTo($('#products'));

            });
        }
    });
});
```

and the asp.net web page have the following list where each item in the list represtns a JSON object:-

```
<h1>All Processes</h1>
<ul id="products"/>
```

But what i am trying to do is instead of just showing the `val.packageName` in the list, to dynamically creates an ajax link for each josn object and when the user clicks on this ajax link to call another API which is `.../web/json/workflow/process/list?packageId=val.packageName` and then display the returned JSON at another list.
But can anyone help me on how i can perform such a functionality?
BR

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's the way to handler events on a list(http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH11.php)

this works perfectly for me with a little alteration...

```
$('ul#products li').click(function(o){
    // alert($(this).text())
    // call your other api here...
});
```

Use it this way:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul#products li', function(e){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Also take a look on those selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Test fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/picklespy/zWQHh/

Just add the list items to the `ul` above and add the following to your javascript code:

```
$('ul#products li').click(function(o){
    // alert($(this).text())
    // call your other api here...
});
```

This will add a click handler to each list item in `<ul id="products">`, which when clicked, will call your second ajax.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in this way the list item packagename will not be shown as Link, it will be shown as text.

Comment: Okay, just for clarity, can you explain what does `shown as link` means...so that i can update my answer correspondingly.

Comment: click-able link such as ajax.actionlinks Or <a>, etc

Comment: Please see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/picklespy/zWQHh/. Regarding ajax.actionLink, i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: i tried you code inside my asp.net application ,,, but no alert will be shown when i click on any of the li. best regards,